# What is the reasoning/intuition behind the solution to this combinatorics problem?

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, combinations

I am reading Principles and Techniques in Combinatorics by Chong and Meng. My question is in regards to the problem below, part (ii). My understanding of the solution is:

The author is basically summing the digits per column( unit digit, tens-digits, etc) by adding the digits in {1,3,5,7} and multiplying this sum by the number of times it repeats in a column. Am I correct?

Also, what is the reasoning for multiplying the sum of the digits in a column by $P^{3}_{i} $ for i=1,2,3? I understand the permutations give the number of times the sum is repeated in a column but I don't understand what the set of 3 elements is ? and why we need a i-permutation of that set?

Any help will be appreciated. Thank you!

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

(i) The computation of the $|S_i|$ is alright.

(ii) After many beginnings I finally managed to comprehend the caprioles undertaken by your author. What I found was not a fine solution of the problem, but an atlas of his grey matter. I strongly suggest that you no longer try to crawl through these windings here.

The $\alpha_i$ can easily be computed as follows: There are $24$ digits occurring in $\alpha_1$, then $24+24=48$ digits occurring in $\alpha_2$, $24+24+12=60$ digits occurring in $\alpha_3$, and $64$ digits occurring in $\alpha_4$. By symmetry we may weigh in each digit with  the average value  ${1+3+5+7\over4}=4$, so that
$$\alpha_1=96,\quad \alpha_2=192,\quad \alpha_3=240,\quad\alpha_4=256$$
and
$$\alpha=1000\alpha_1+100\alpha_2+10\alpha_3+\alpha_4=117\,856\ .$$

Comment: Thank you Christian. Your explanation makes the solution more clear. I'm still wondering where P (3,2) comes from though, but for now, i will stay away from the windings per your suggestion.